# Run this bat file with admin rights

Tags: batch-file, uac, silverlight, login-script

I have written a simple bat file to run a silverlight install at login.

I have the script called via GPO and AD, but when it runs, i have the issue of admin rights and UAC.

Is there a way to stream the admin username and password into the script so it will install??

> `setlocal
>
> set
>   DeployServer=\10.0.30.7\installs\Silverlight\
>
> set InstallerName=Silverlight.exe /q
>
> Set
>   LogLocation=\10.0.30.7\installs\SilverlightLogs
>
> REM
>   ************************************************************************* REM Deployment code begins here. Do
>   not modify anything below this line.
>   REM
>
> ---
>
> reg query
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight
>   if %errorlevel%==1 (goto
>   DeploySilverlight) else (goto End)
>
> REM If 1 returned, the product was not
>   found. Run setup here.
>   :DeploySilverlight start /wait
>   %DeployServer%\%InstallerName% echo
>   %date% %time% Setup ended with error
>   code %errorlevel%. >>
>   %LogLocation%\%computername%.txt
>
> REM If 0 or other was returned, the
>   product was found or another error
>   occurred. Do nothing. :End
>
> Endlocal

This is what i have so far.

Comment: i have local admin rights across the domain, but need to export the bat to other users as a logon script.

I have tried using the runas command and piping in the password but only get errors.

Thanks
F

Comment: I don't know much GPO, but I think you are probably doing it the wrong way. The GPO that triggers the install should apply to the machine instead of to a user. Microsoft has other way of deploying software unattended than what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native runas cannot be passed a password, you'd have to use a 3rd party app. The following is free, the full version allows you to encrypt the password:

**http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/53.htm**

Then you could call the batchfile from within another batchfile containing the following:

runas user@domain.com password yourbatchfile.bat

That's about the best solution I can come up with for you ...